# Promise resolver [object Array] is not a function

Tags: puppeteer

I have a script that asks for the user input to download (or not) a file. It's fairly straight forward, but I have a problem with the following piece of code. If the user chooses "NO", then the else if condition works fine and the code finishes its expected execuetion. But if the user chooses Yes, the file gets downloaded but I get the following error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Promise resolver [object Array] is not a function
```

I problably need to learn more about Promises, but I share the section of the code that fails in case I am making an obvious mistake that I fail to see.

```
async function download_fallo(page) {

    if (download == "Y") {
      
        await new Promise([
          page.click('div > div.col-xs-12.col-sm-11 > div.row > div.col-sm-4.col-lg-3 > a'),
          //page.wait({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' }) // does not work either
          //page.wait(2000) // UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning page.wait is not a function... 
          ]);
        return console.log("Perfect")
      } else if (download == "N") {
        console.log("Just the information then!") }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont really know what you need because i need more context, but if you want to execute an array of promises you could try

`Promise.all([ promise1, promise2 ])`

This method takes an array of promises as an input, and returns a single Promise as an output. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: This, and you need `page.waitFor(2000)` or `page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' })` instead of `page.wait(...)`. See API docs: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pagewaitforselectororfunctionortimeout-options-args and https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pagewaitfornavigationoptions

Comment: Usually if you need more context to answer you should ask in the comments to the question.

Comment: Yes but I havent enough reputation :( and i wanna help

Answer (score 3):

Thanks guys --- I was making obvious mistakes and you clarified them. I was not using Promise.all and made a mistake with page.await, both were pointed out. With that corrected, the code works. I post below in case someone finds it useful, it's a simple if condition tied to a readLine user input to download (or not) a PDF file from a website.

```
async function download_fallo(page) {

    if (download == "Y") {
        await Promise.all([
          page.click('div > div.col-xs-12.col-sm-11 > div.row > div.col-sm-4.col-lg-3 > a'),
          page.waitFor(2000) 
          ]);
        return console.log("Perfect")
      } else if (download == "N") {
        console.log("Just the information then!") }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not a 100% sure if your script does what you expect to do, but ‘page.wait’ is a non-existent puppeteer method. You need [‘page.waitFor’](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v4.0.0&show=api-pagewaitforselectororfunctionortimeout-options-args) if you want to wait for / pause the script for certain ms-s.